# Excel VBA unable to click a button on web page

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, buttonclick

I have done a lot of internet explorer automation with excel but this has gotten me stumped.

I have a page with a button with the code:-

```
<a class="button button-bg multi-search-add">add</a>
```

I need to click this button to enter a pincode data into the form but i'm not being able to do that

I've tried

```
Dim objButtonAll As Object
Dim objButton As Object
Set objButtonAll = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each objButton In objButtonAll
If objButton.className = "button button-bg multi-search-add" Then
objButton.Click  
End If
Next
```

and I've also tried

```
Dim objButtonAll As Object
Dim objButton As Object
Set objButtonAll = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each objButton In objButtonAll
If objButton.innerText = "add" Then
objButton.Click  
End If
Next
```

and tried

```
Dim objButtonAll As Object
Dim objButton As Object
Dim objA As HTMLInputButtonElement

Set objButtonAll = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each objButton In objButtonAll
If objButton.innerText = "add" Then
objA=objButton 'I get an error here
objA.Click  
End If
Next
```

The first two codes can identify the point but the objButton.click does nothing. The third code snip gives an error that the **"Object Variable or with Block Variable not set"**

BTW this is the 130th "a" element in the page, the 129th "a" element the "order statuses" link is easily clicked.

The snap of the website is as below.

[image]

Also it seems that this part of the code is implemented in Javascript as I cant find this button in the source HTML file.

Any Ideas?

PS. Sendkeys works here ... about 50% of the time.

Comment: Any associated javascript events?